# Fixed position of ImageButton on a GestureImageView

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a project which adds pinpoints to a map. For the map we use a GestureImageView to make it scrollable and for the buttons ImageButton.

But following problem is happening: Whenever we move the map, we have to make sure the pinpoints remain in position.

The problem with this is that we call the ImageButton's translation function from another thread inside the GestureImageView and you're not allowed to call that view.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GestureImageViewAnimator
Process: nl.example.android, PID: 17024
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6915)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChildFast(ViewGroup.java:4639)
    at android.view.View.invalidateViewProperty(View.java:11748)
    at android.view.View.setTranslationY(View.java:11102)
    at nl.example.android.GestureImageView.setPosition(GestureImageView.java:455)
    at nl.example.android.GestureImageViewTouchListener.handleDrag(GestureImageViewTouchListener.java:449)
    at nl.example.android.GestureImageViewTouchListener$1.onMove(GestureImageViewTouchListener.java:122)
    at nl.example.android.FlingAnimation.update(FlingAnimation.java:49)
    at nl.example.android.Animator.run(Animator.java:45)
```

What I've tried now: The class for the activity context

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = this;
    }
}
```

The code in GestureImageView:

```
final float transX = x;
MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();
myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        setTranslationY(transX);
    }
});
```

The code in MainActivity:

```
MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pin1.setTranslationY(3);
        synchronized(this){
            this.notify();
        }
    }
};

synchronized(runnable) {
    myActivity.runOnUiThread(runnable);
    runnable.wait() ; // unlocks myRunable while waiting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In file GestureImageView, line 455 try it:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        setTranslationZ(x);
    }
});
```

You can't invoke views function from others Thread. You must invoke it on main. If you want to wait for end execute runOnUiThread, use this:

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){public void run(){
        setTranslationZ(...);
        synchronized(this){
            this.notify();
        }
    }};
    synchronized( myRunnable ) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(myRunnable);
        myRunnable.wait() ; // unlocks myRunable while waiting
    }
```

Edit for people, who don't know, how to use runOnUiThread:

```
class GestureImageView extends View{
    private long thread;
    public GestureImageView(Context c){
        super(c);
        thread=Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
    public void setTranslationZ(final int n){
        if(thread==Thread.currentThread().getId()){ //this is UI thread
            super.setTranslationZ(n); 
        } else {
            MainActivity.instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        setTranslationZ(n);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
public static Activity instance;
public MainActivity(){
    instance=this;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
}
```

Comment: How can I implement the activity.runOnUiThread when GestureImageView is not an Activity.

Comment: Save activity to field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044163/starting-an-android-activity-from-a-static-method replace "Context" with "Activity".

Comment: Updated the question with your answer, but I don't get how I should implement that.

Comment: Gott... Why you creating a new instance?

Comment: I should use static method getAcitivity in MyActivity right? But that's not my  problem, I don't know what I can use instead of "myRunnable".

Comment: You can use static method and static field. There isn't diffrents. Please copy and paste my code from "setTranslationZ(..) . It should works.