# run startService in static method

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

i have this function as static method:

```
    public static void engine(SQLiteDatabase mydb){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GPSLocation.class);
        intent.putExtra("sql_obj", mydb); 
        startService(intent);
    }
```

but startService return follow error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   startService(Intent) from the type ContextWrapper

is there any way to startService in static method?

Comment: [context.startService(intent);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044163/starting-an-android-activity-from-a-static-method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've already got a reference to a `Context` class via `context` variable (since you are using it to create intent `Intent intent = new Intent(context, GPSLocation.class);`), so you can start it from the static context in the following way:

```
context.startService(intent)
```